# could not generate docker image in windows 10

Tags: python, docker

I use docker in windows 10 to get the docker image to deploy in Linux server.
This error occurs when I run`docker build . -t webapp`:

```
    1004.8       building '_cffi_backend' extension
#9 1004.8       creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7
#9 1004.8       creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/c
#9 1004.8       gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -DTHREAD_STACK_SIZE=0x100000 -fPIC -DUSE__THREAD -DHAVE_SYNC_SYNCHRONIZE -I/usr/include/ffi -I/usr/include/libffi -I/usr/local/include/python3.7m -c c/_cffi_backend.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/c/_cffi_backend.o
#9 1004.8       c/_cffi_backend.c:15:10: fatal error: ffi.h: No such file or directory
#9 1004.8          15 | #include <ffi.h>
#9 1004.8             |          ^~~~~~~
#9 1004.8       compilation terminated.
#9 1004.8       error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
#9 1004.8       ----------------------------------------
#9 1004.8       ERROR: Failed building wheel for cffi
#9 1004.8     ERROR: Failed to build one or more wheels
#9 1004.8     Traceback (most recent call last):
#9 1004.8       File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/installer.py", line 75, in fetch_build_egg
#9 1004.8         subprocess.check_call(cmd)
#9 1004.8       File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 363, in check_call
#9 1004.8         raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
#9 1004.8     subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/usr/local/bin/python', '-m', 'pip', '--disable-pip-version-check', 'wheel', '--no-deps', '-w', '/tmp/tmp52wt384_', '--quiet', 'cffi>=1.1.0']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
#9 1004.8
#9 1004.8     The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
#9 1004.8
#9 1004.8     Traceback (most recent call last):
#9 1004.8       File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
#9 1004.8       File "/tmp/pip-install-u5y47qex/pynacl_5451ac7819b14cbfbc96c991cc149641/setup.py", line 259, in <module>
#9 1004.8         "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.5",
#9 1004.8       File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 152, in setup
#9 1004.8         _install_setup_requires(attrs)
#9 1004.8       File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 147, in _install_setup_requires
#9 1004.8         dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
#9 1004.8       File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 689, in fetch_build_eggs
#9 1004.8         replace_conflicting=True,
#9 1004.8       File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 768, in resolve
#9 1004.8         replace_conflicting=replace_conflicting
#9 1004.8       File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1051, in best_match
#9 1004.8         return self.obtain(req, installer)
#9 1004.8       File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1063, in obtain
#9 1004.8         return installer(requirement)
#9 1004.8       File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 745, in fetch_build_egg
#9 1004.8         return fetch_build_egg(self, req)
#9 1004.8       File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/installer.py", line 77, in fetch_build_egg
#9 1004.8         raise DistutilsError(str(e)) from e
#9 1004.8     distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Command '['/usr/local/bin/python', '-m', 'pip', '--disable-pip-version-check', 'wheel', '--no-deps', '-w', '/tmp/tmp52wt384_', '--quiet', 'cffi>=1.1.0']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

My dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine

MAINTAINER Robley Gori <ro6ley.github.io>

EXPOSE 8000

RUN apk add --no-cache gcc python3-dev musl-dev

ADD . /webapp

WORKDIR /webapp

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

RUN C:\Users\Scripts\python.exe webapp/manage.py makemigrations

RUN C:\Users\Scripts\python.exe webapp/manage.py migrate

CMD ["C:\Users\Scripts\python.exe","webapp/manage.py","runserver","0.0.0.0:8000" ]
```

Comment: Looks like a missing library. And BTW Docker is Linux, on Linux there are no `C:\...` paths.

Comment: I use docker in my windows 10 system. My dev computer is windows 10

Comment: @Django I don't think you understood what Klaus was saying. `python:3.7-alpine` is a linux based image. Your `CMD` is wrong because you're giving it a windows path not a path in the linux container.

Comment: how to change "python:3.7-alpine" to the one in windows? I copy this cmd from somewhere else

Comment: @Django: There is no need to change to anything 'in Windows'. Docker containers run in an isolated environment, not on your host. There's a python:3.7-windowsservercore, but this will still run isolated from your host OS.

Comment: @TekkiI tried both python:3.7-alpine and  python:3.7-windowsservercore, all show errors

Comment: @Django: In any case you have to install `libffi-dev` because of the compiler error.